# What is a derivative of this equation?

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of $x^2+y^2=1$? I know I'm supposed to subtract the $x^2$, but I don't know where to go from there?

Comment: in respect to x?

Comment: Do you want to take the derivative of $y$? That is, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$? You can only take the derivative of a function, not an equation.

Comment: If you want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, you can either solve for y first and then differentiate, or you can use implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^2+y^2=1$ is not a function (it's actually the equation of a circle), we have to use implicit differentiation.

\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+y^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(1)\\
&\implies 2x+2yy'=0\\
&\implies 2yy'=-2x\\
&\implies y'=\frac{-2x}{2y}\\
&\implies y'=-\frac{x}{y}
\end{align*}

Comment: So the equation y′=−x/y is the derivative of the circle equation?

Comment: That is correct. Whenever you have an equation that can't be expressed as a function, you take the derivative with respect to $x$ of both sides and then solve for $y'$.

Comment: That you for the information

Answer (score 0):

If we want to differentiate with respect to $x$ we can just differentiate both sides to get
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) + \frac{d}{dx}(y^2) = 0.
$$
Now we can use the chain rule to get
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(y^2) = \frac{d(y^2)}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}.
$$
Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 0):

When we use "implicit differentiation" it isn't necessary to move the terms around.  The derivative (with respect to $x$) of $x^2$ we get $2x$.  We use the chair rule to find the derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $x$ to get $2y\frac{dy}{dx}$ because $y$ is a function of $x$.  The derivative of 1 is zero, so the equation becomes $2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$.  Now you can solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.